# Как мне удалить таблицу?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Вопрос в заголовке, не получается удалить таблицу, делаю так -

```
public void dropUsersTable() {
     session.beginTransaction();
     SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("drop table users");
     session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Имя таблицы - `users`

Создается она на основе класса `User.class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запрос вы создали, но не используете его. Вам не хватает `executeUpdate();`

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("drop table users"); // создание запроса
query.executeUpdate(); // выполнение запроса
```

Comment: Спасибо,а есть другой способ удаления ?

Comment: а что вы имеете в виду *другой способ удаления*? Знаком пока только с *создать запрос - выполнить*